# Method return variables

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i writing a little game for study and i am stuck, i have a class where i have methods for generate reports, and when i call any method from Controller site this one return me class variables in object.

Call method _Get or _Create returns:

```
{"id":null,"character_id":1,"name":null,"desc":null}
```

Class:

```
class GenerateRaport {
    public $id;
    public $character_id;
    public $name;
    public $desc;

    public function _Get() {
        $raport = PlayerRaport::where('character_id', $this->character_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return $raport;
    }

    public function _Create() {
        $new = new PlayerRaport();
        $new->character_id = $this->character_id;
        $new->name = $this->name;
        $new->desc = $this->desc;
        $new->save();
        return $new;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class RaportController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {
        $raport = new GenerateRaport();
        $raport->character_id = \Auth::user()->character_id;
        $raport->_Get();
        return response()->json($raport, 200);
    }

    public function create(Request $request) {
        $raport = new GenerateRaport();
        $raport->character_id = \Auth::user()->character_id;
        $raport->name = "Name";
        $raport->desc = "Description";
        $raport->_Create();
        return response()->json($raport, 201);
    }
}
```

@Edit:

```
class PlayerRaport extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'desc', 'character_id', 'viewed'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];
}
```

Comment: It could be that the problem is in `PlayerRaport` class. But without the code of that class, is difficult to answer. You did not post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: PlayerRaport is a simple model, i am added now :)

Comment: Could you please tell more about what you tring to do and what is your blocking point?

Comment: I think, into ```RaportController``` the lastest two string in each methods have to be ```$result = $raport->_Get(); return response()->json($result, 200);``` and ```$result = $raport->_Create(); return response()->json($result, 201);```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing your returned value into your response that's why your json values are null. (Refer to @Jigius comment)

Furthermore, I see you created `GenerateReport` so that `viewed` information is not display in `json` response.

While your implementation is ok, you could also have a look into Laravel's [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources) (`Resource Collections` if you return multiple rows). 
You can save lot of effort by implement eloquent-resources to your solution.

Sample of find one

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class PlayerRaport extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'desc' => $this->desc,
            'character_id' => $this->character_id
        ];
    }
}
```

```
use App\PlayerRaport;
use App\Http\Resources\PlayerRaport as PlayerRaportResource;

class RaportController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request) {
        return new PlayerRaportResource(PlayerRaport::find(1));
    }
}
```